Upcrossing Lemma for backwards martingales
Context
Let $(X_{-n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a backward martingale.
I am currently reading the last chapter of Probability Essentials by Jacod and Protter and aim to produce a proof of the up-crossing lemma for backward martingales.
I must prove that
$$
E[U_{-n}] \leq \dfrac{1}{b-a} \cdot E\left[(-X_0-a)^{+}\right], 
$$
where $U_{-n}$ as the number of upcrossings of $(-X_{-k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}},$ and $a$ and $b$ are real numbers with $b>a.$
Here is my attempt to define the up-crossings, $U_{-n}$, up to $-n$.
I don't understand why the author defines $U_{-n}$ as the number of upcrossings of $(-X_{-k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}.$
Here is my attempt to define the stopping times for the backward martingale process:

Define $ T_0 = 0 $ and
$$
   S_{-j-1} = \max\{-K < T_{-j} : -X_{-k} \leq a \}.
   $$

Define
$$
   T_{-j-1} = \max\{-K < S_{-j-1} : -X_{-k} \geq b \}.
   $$

Let
$$
   U_{-n} = \max\{-K : T_k \geq -n \}.
   $$

Define
$$
   Y_{-n} = (-X_{-n} - a)^+ = \psi(-X_{-n}),
   $$
so
$$
   E[\psi(-X_{-m})] \leq E[\psi(-X_{-n})], \quad n < m,
   $$
because the positive part is a convex function.



Question on stopping times
Is the notion of stopping time reverted for backward martingales? Meaning do we have to verify this property?
$$
   \{ T \geq -n \} \in \mathcal{F}_{-n}.
$$

Preliminary Observations
After these definitions, I tried to proceed like in the martingale case
First of all we have $T_{-n-1} < -n$ because by definition at least n instants have to pass to have $T_{-n-1}$ crossings of the upper bound $b.$
Given $ T_{-n-1} < -n $, we write:
$$
Y_{-n} = Y_{T_{-1} \vee -n} + \sum_{i=1}^m \left( Y_{S_{-i} \vee -n} - Y_{T_{-i} \vee -n} \right) + \sum_{i=1}^m Y_{T_{-i-1} \vee -n} - Y_{S_{-i} \vee -n}.
$$

Key observation on upcrossings
Each upcrossing of $(-X_{-n})$ up to the time $-n$ corresponds to an interger $i$, such that:
$$
-n \leq T_{-i} \leq S_{-i} \quad \text{with } Y_{S_{-i}} = 0.
$$
Additionally:
$$
Y_{T_{-i}} = Y_{T_{-i} \vee -n} \geq b - a,
$$
while
$$
Y_{S_{-i} \vee -n} - Y_{T_{-i} \vee -n} \leq 0 \quad \forall i.
$$
Because $Y_{T_{-i} \vee -n} \geq b - a$ and $Y_{S_{-i} \vee -n} = 0$, we have:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^m \left( Y_{T_{-i-1} \vee -n} - Y_{S_{-i} \vee -n} \right) \geq (b - a) \cdot U_{-n}.
$$
Thus:
$$
(b - a) \cdot U_{-n} \leq Y_{-n} - Y_{T_{-1} \vee -n} - \sum_{i=1}^m Y_{T_{-i} \vee -n} - Y_{S_{-i}\vee -n}.
$$
Issue

Finally,
$$
T_{-i} \vee -n \leq S_{-i} \vee -n,
$$
but this is not what I need because I need the expectation of
$$
\sum_{i=1}^m Y_{T_{-i} \vee -n} - Y_{S_{-i}\vee -n}.
$$
to be positive. Where did I go wrong? I must have confused some definitions—perhaps I need to swap the roles of $S$ and $T$. Was I mistaken about the definition of stopping times? Or did I misapply the inequality involving expectations?
It is crucial for me to deepen my understanding of stochastic processes to resolve these uncertainties!

Sorry, I found the answer in Grimmett's book! One simply has to observe that the process $X_{-n}, \dots, X_{0}$ is a martingale and use the previous result about up-crossings in the martingale case!
In the end, one might say that a backward martingale is a glance at the end of a martingale that never truly begins.
